# «За номером» или «под номером»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Вот такой вопрос, возникший в споре с моим начальником: надо было оформить документ, в котором было упомянуто **"письмо ФГУП «Почта России» под номером"** (так написал я), она увидела этот документ и сказала, что это неграмотно, правильно **"за номером"**. Мне непонятно, с чего это вдруг грамотно в данном случае "за номером"? Подскажите, как верно, грамотно?

Answer (score 4):

Словарь "Управление в русском языке" говорит, что "за номером" — это официальный стиль:

> [НОМЕР](http://m.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80&all=x) — под номером, (офиц.) за номером. Дом под номером первым / под номером один / номер один; Приказ за номером первым / за номером один / номер один.

В Нацкорпусе встречается 145 раз. Возможно, так принято говорить и писать в профессиональной среде. Но в любом случае "письмо под номером N" — корректно.

> [Вопрос № 203539](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=203539)
>   Как правильно: На ваш запрос номер или На ваш запрос под номером?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Возможны оба варианта.

Comment: *>> Как правильно: На ваш запрос номер или На ваш запрос под номером?* Но "за номером" здесь нет.

Comment: @Niemand Ответы Грамоты по поводу "за номером" приведены в ответе Ксении. А я хотел подчеркнуть, что "под номером" - правильно.

Answer (score 4):

Оба варианта грамматически возможны, но в канцелярском контексте они неравноценны: универсальный, "бытовой" вариант "**под номером**" может восприниматься как *документ из нумерованного списка* разнородных приложений к чему-либо (дополнительно требуется отсылка к такому списку), вариант же "**за номером**" (в силу сложившихся деловых условностей) указывает на присвоенный документу *постоянный номер регистрации*, вписываемый в сам документ. В отличие от порядкового номера, такой номер может помимо цифр содержать иные символы. Поскольку одновременно могут сосуществовать оба вида присвоения номера (присвоенный при создании или при регистрации документа номер и номер упоминания документа в списке, на который ссылаются), вариант "за" можно трактовать не просто как *"проявление делового стиля"*, а как ссылку на конкретный вид нумерации (номер, присвоенный документу постоянно, напр. вписанный в него). Поэтому возникновение такого варианта могло быть вызвано функциональной необходимостью. Пример:

> письмо такое-то **за** номером  **34-15А/2018** (документ **под** номером **12** в
>   Приложении).

Что касается реакции начальника: в предположении, что речь идёт заведомо о номере, вписанном в документ при его регистрации, в контескте изложенного вариант "**под номером**" воспринимается как смысловая *неточность* или *неопределённость*.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего начальница права, так действительно пишут, это своего рода сленг.

Answer (score 2):

У Грамоты.ру есть материал на эту тему:
[http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=за%20номер](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80)

```
Вопрос № 213307
```

Корректно ли написание "за номером" в следующем предложении: "Предприятие зарегистрировано за номером 413". Спасибо.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
**Правильно: *под номером*.**

```
Вопрос № 270080
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, корректно ли употребление фразы "разрешение (постановление) за номером 2530"? Или же лучше просто использовать знак №: постановление №2530?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Можно использовать знак или слово: **постановление номер... разрешение номер...**

Получается, что регистрируют письмо **под номером** или оно числится под номером, а называется **письмо ФГУП «Почта России» №...**. Но на практике выражение *документ за номером*  встречается часто. Возможно, это канцелярский термин, отчасти устаревающий, но еще используемый.

**Из Нацкорпуса**

1)  **Проект закона за номером 304493-5** был внесен депутатами-единороссами Олегом Валенчуком и Мартином Шаккумом. [Светлана Сухова. Отнять и не делить // «Огонек», 2014]

2) Он **числится** среди вещественных доказательств **под номером** первым. [Игорь Ефимов. Суд да дело // «Звезда», 2001]

Answer (score 1):

**Подскажите, как верно, грамотно?**

Допустимы оба варианта, но каждый из Вас прав по-своему. Вы имели право написать "под номером", начальница имела право Вас поправить в том случае, если в Вашей организации принято другое написание.

Приведу фрагмент цитаты из избранных трудов по русскому языку Н.Ю. Шведовой (там целая страница интересных наблюдений, но я не могу скопировать, а набирать руками немного лень; желающие смогут найти по приведенному фрагменту в гугло-книгах):

> В сочетании со словами *приказ, бумага, распоряжение* и под. сохраняются как норма группы **за номером** (*приказ за номером сто два*) и **под номером** (*распоряжение под номером сто четыре*); зато не употребительны словосочетания вроде *приказ сто два*; в официальной речи наиболее употребительно сочетание типа *приказ номер два*.

Слово **номер** с другими словами может сочетаться совсем иначе — об этом рассказывается в книге. Считаю труды Н.Ю. Шведовой более авторитетным источником, чем Грамоту.ру.

Comment: Если начальник сказала "Так неграмотно", то она неправа. Но если она сказала "Так неправильно", то, возможно, она права (если в организации принято писать "за номером").

Comment: @М_Г Интересно, допустимо ли говорить "начальник сказала"? Я сначала тоже так написал, но потом решил, что это неверно.

Comment: Почему нет? (Если точно известно, что начальник — женщина.)

Comment: "сказуемое может быть поставлено в женском роде, если его форма является единственным показателем того, что речь идет о женщине" (http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/letters?id=59)

Comment: @М_Г У меня сомнения были в подлежащем, а не в сказуемом. По приведенной Вами ссылке нет слова "начальник". При этом в толковом словаре в статье "начальник" слово "начальница" присутствует (в отличие от "экспертша", например). Я перестраховался — заменил на безопасное "начальница".

Comment: @grizzly Авторитеты,  авторитеты, кто авторитетнее, тот и прав. А как же истина,  вдруг оба авторитета ошибаются? У нас есть три варианта: номер, под номером, за номером, в каждом заложен определенный смысл, каждый подходит под определенную ситуацию.

Comment: Мне кажется так. Номер - общее определение, под номером -  временное определение (на текущую ситуацию), за номером - постоянное определение (канцелярит).  Письмо за номером - неплохой вариант. Речь идет о регистрации, которая не изменится. Письмо номер?  А вдруг это номер по порядку поступления или еще что-нибудь. Письмо под номером - на регистрацию мало похоже. Это участники конкурса обычно выступают под номером.

Comment: @Ксения Кто постановил, что  под номером — временное определение?  17 августа 1946 года Сталин подписывает Постановление Совета Министров СССР под номером 1815-782с. [Вадим Жотиков, Александр Максимычев. Петр Капица: малоизвестные страницы из жизни // «За науку», 2014]

Comment: Поднимаю Шурика на ноги (он, кстати, оказался астеником), тащу к двери под номером 1406. [Екатерина Завершнева. Высотка (2012)]

Comment: 7 марта премьер Михаил Касьянов подписал распоряжение правительства под номером 278-р [Кампанейщина. Чиновники заменяют работу «отчетами о проделанной работе» (2002) // «Известия», 2002.03.26]

Comment: @grizzly У Рoзнеталя: начальник лаборатории кандидат химических наук В. К. Леонова

Comment: @М_Г Не совсем то. "Начальник лабаратории" — это должность. "Начальник лаборатории меня уволила" звучит вполне нормально. А "моя начальник меня уволила" немного режет слух, согласитесь. Я вроде разобрался — см. ограниченный перечень слов [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/59-rubric-89).

Comment: @М_Г Кто постановил? В словарь надо посмотреть, где указано значение предлога ПОД.  8.  Указывает на предмет, имеющийся при другом предмете (обычно как его составная часть или характерный признак). Дом под железной крышей. Судно под российским флагом.// С приправой из чего-л. Рыба под соусом. Селёдка под шубой.  Крышу можно поменять, флаг тоже, ну и соус, разумеется.  Всё это временно, всё это не постоянное определение. Ну есть какая-то статистика употребления, или хотят что-то изменить/отменить. Надо же понять, что, как и почему делают, а не только как это обычно делают.

Comment: @grizzly В современном русском языке для названия большинства профессий, в которых заняты женщины наравне с мужчинами, возникли параллельные формы, например: начальник - начальница, певец -певица, продавец - продавщица, летчик - летчица, спортсмен -спортсменка, чемпион - чемпионка, фигурист - фигуристка.

В использовании таких парных слов наметилось разграничение: в официальном стиле употребляются только слова мужского рода, хотя слова женского рода также вполне литературны.
Источник: 
Жилина О.А., Романова Н.Н. - Русский язык и культура речи. ч.1. Основы культуры речи - 2008

Comment: @grizzly "Моя начальник меня уволила" неверно, а верно: "мой начальник меня уволила" или "моя начальница меня уволила", второе - менее официально.

Comment: @М_Г Спасибо, это звучит убедительно. Хотя должен признать, что мне это совсем не нравится. Я ни разу в жизни не встречал выражения "оперная певец" или "оперный певец" в отношении женщин даже в официальном стиле.

Comment: @М_Г Ага, я понял: при наличии определения преимущество отдаётся женскому роду (даже в официальном стиле).

Comment: @grizzly "Певец" в отношении женщин — я тоже не видел такого, кажется, никогда.

Comment: @Ксения Крышу можно поменять, а номер  нельза? Судно под флагом, а документ под номером — прекрасная аналогия.

Comment: Нельзя поменять. Регистрация - это очень серьезно,  это присвоение номера документу, и исправления в регистрационном журнале не допускаются.  Если исправите один номер, все остальные тоже будете менять?  Или под этим номером другое письмо запишете?  Это всё незаконные операции, подделка документов.

Comment: @Ксения Дом под крышей — это расположение в пространстве. Нет намека на временную связь. Книга под названием - вот хороший пример.

Comment: Зачем Вам намек на временную связь, значение предлога дается в обобщенном виде. И книга под названием - это сначала книга, а сверху название, которое можно поменять. А вот письмо за номером - это сначала номер, а к нему (на нем) письмо. Номер идет сначала!